# Javascript location reload without get perimeter

Tags: php, javascript

How can I make "`location.reload()`" on php file without get perimeter ?

Here is an example..

Let's say I have PHP, and at the right top, I have logout button.

When user press that button, PHP will automatically re-direct to "`index.php?logout`" and after that, i will logout (unset cookie and other) and return `( javascript location.reload() )` to main page (login page)

Problem that I have is, when php return to login page after logout, then url is still "`index.php?logout`", so when user login back with "`index.php?logout`" page, it will automatically logout (because of ?logout perimeter on url)..

So how can I tackle this problem ? Anybody got any idea ?

I hope you all understand what i'm trying to tell you all about..

Thanks for reading this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `self.location.reload` instead of `location.reload`. Because `location.reload` reloads the current page. You can simple use

```
 self.location.reload = index.php
```

Or you can remove query paramter from your url like

```
var url = 'index.php?logout'
url=url.split("?")[0];
location.reload =url
```

Comment: thanks for example, however, location.reload doesn't work for me, but, location.href work for me..btw, thanks for that split function, its work for me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

you  re-direct to login page and save page url that request for login that is `index.php?logout` for re-direct back you must check perimeter `logout` if exist remove it from return   url for example

```
//replace parent::$Patch with your root url like "http://localhost/myapp/"
if(!parent::$Patch.'admin/login.php'=='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']){//check if you are in login.php page didn't redirect to login.php
 if(!@header('Location:'.parent::$Patch.'admin/login.php?url='.rawurlencode(str_replace("logout","",'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])))){
       //if header error echo javaScript code for re-direct
      ?>
                         <!DOCTYPE HTML>
                         <html>
                         <head>
                         <script language="javascript">  
                           var LoadP = <?php print "'".parent::$Patch.'admin/login.php?url='.rawurlencode(str_replace("logout","",'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))."'"?>;
                           self.location = LoadP; 
                         </script></head></html>
                         <?php  
                        }
                        exit();

   }

}
```

this code re-direct  user to login page and keep return url of page. if `logout` exist inside of return url remove it

i hope it can help you

Comment: redirect using javascript is generally a bad idea unless unavoidable. here it is avoidable.

Comment: i put Both re-direct way header and JavaScript

Comment: you are suppressing an error rather than solving it. an error in header will create fatal error and hence the folowed codes won't get executed. So those javascript codes are pointless at this moment above.

Comment: no error in header but some time error happen for echo before header for that i put `@` before header if happen  use JavaScript For Re-direct

Comment: actually that was the point. if there is an error in header, those javascripts will never execute.

Comment: `@` is Error Control Operators http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php before header is for this in this case if error happen execution  didn't stop

Comment: _from the same page._ Currently the "@" error-control operator prefix will even disable error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script execution. Among other things, this means that if you use "@" to suppress errors from a certain function and either it isn't available or has been mistyped, **the script will die right there with no indication as to why.** _an error in header returns fatal error._

Comment: as far as i know header only `Warning` if echo before it like <b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at E:\xampp\htdocs\2\1.php:8) in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\2\1.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />

Answer (score 0):

location.reload()  reloads the current page with the post data,you should use window.location.href in case of login/logout

Answer (score 0):

> When user press that button, PHP will automatically re-direct to "index.php?logout" and >after that, i will logout (unset cookie and other) and return ( javascript location.reload() >) to main page (login page)

all these can be implemented in server side.

```
// LOGOUT
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){ 
//logout code
}

header('location: www.yoursite.com/login') //or whatever the url is
exit;
```

Comment: I already think about this, but this method also work, but i just need to do in javascript :)